# Having trouble with Jquery modal dialog not properly loading ui-overlay

Tags: jquery, overlay, modal-dialog

So, the test site is up at http://kinnill.com/dev/eisatech and this is going to sound extremely awkward, but there are two separate modal dialog windows that open from the "About" and "Contact" links. The "About" dialog opens and closes perfectly fine, but the "Contact" dialog only loads the modal overlay if "About" hasn't loaded. I have looked at the site in firebug, and it seems that if you try to load the "Contact" dialog second, the .ui-overlay div  is never created.

The javascript call is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 420,
        width: 661,
        modal: true
    });

    $( ".contact" )
        .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });

    $( "#dialog-about" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 420,
        width: 661,
        modal: true
    });

    $( ".about" )
        .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-about" ).dialog( "open" );
        }); 

    $(".contact")
        .click(function() {
            $("#dialog-about").dialog("close");
        });

});
</script>
```

#dialog-form is the "Contact" dialog, and #dialog-about is the "About" dialog. The extra 'close' call is because there is a link in the About dialog to open the Contact dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest a better way for creating and closing jquery dialogs. Even me I had the same problems when using more dialogs at the same page but I definitively resolved this way:

```
$( ".about" ).click(function() {
 $("<div />").dialog({
  open: function()
  {
    $(this).html( $( "#dialog-about" ).html());
  },
  height: 420,
  width: 661,
  modal: true,
  close:function()
  {
    $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
  }
 });
}); 

$( ".contact" ).click(function() {
 $("<div />").dialog({
  open: function()
  {
    $(this).html( $( "#dialog-form" ).html());
  },
  height: 420,
  width: 661,
  modal: true,
  close:function()
  {
    $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
  }
 });
});
```

Just create the dialogs on the fly and when you close them get remove totally without conflicts.

Comment: It seems to be working, but the content in the dialogs now takes a good  20 seconds to appear. And the link that is inside the about dialog, that needs to close it and open the contact dialog no longer works.

Comment: 20 seconds?? Are them loaded with ajax or they are just loaded with the page in hidden mode?

Comment: Just loaded with the page, when I click the link now, the dialog shows up blank, and then eventually the content appears.

Comment: have you put online the new changes? I cannot see them on the site you posted.

Comment: I just tested and it is working fine, really fine. Dialoges are opened instantly.

Comment: Hm, they don't seem to load slowly online for me... Although the link inside the about window doesn't work.

Comment: Just give an id or class to the link and add to the same event to the contact link: $( ".contact, .link-contact" ).click....